# No se ejecuta la búsqueda usando DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Trato de realizar una búsqueda dinámica en una tabla usando [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) pero no realiza las búsquedas, ni siquiera pasa por el `console` del `keyup` para realizar la búsqueda.

Tengo un input con la clase `searchInTable`:

```
<input type = "text" class = "searchInTable border form-control">
```

Creo y configuro la tabla con una función declarada dentro del evento `$(document).ready:

```
var initTableWithSearch = function() {

    var table = $('#ExampleList');
    var settings = {
        sDom: "<t><''<p>>",
        destroy: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        aoColumnDefs: [
            {"bVisible": true, "aTargets": [0]},
            {"bVisible": false, "aTargets": [1]}
        ]
    };

    table.dataTable(settings);
```

Antes de cerrar la función, ahí mismo hago la búsqueda:

```
    var timeout;
    var delay = 500;
    $('.searchInTable').keyup(function (e) {
        console.log("searchInTable keyup");
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            table.DataTable().search($(this).val()).draw();
        }, delay);
    });
};
```

Y después de hacer la configuración se llama a la función:

```
initTableWithSearch();
```

Trato de realizar la búsqueda abajo de la llamada de la función pero tampoco realiza la búsqueda. He intentando también realizar la búsqueda desde la consola como:

```
$('#ExampleList').DataTable().search("hola").draw();
```

Pero tampoco me realiza la búsqueda, en su lugar me lanza el siguiente *warning*:

> DataTables warning: table id=ExampleList - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see [datatables.net/tn/4](https://datatables.net/tn/4)

Comment: al realizar la busqueda desde consola aparece el siguiente error                                        DataTables warning: table id=ExampleList - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es un error muy común cuando se trabaja con `JavaScript`, y es no saber muy bien a qué corresponde `this` en cada momento. Si no prestas cuidado puedes estar haciendo referencia, como en este caso, al objeto equivocado.

Primeramente es bueno leer lo que dice de `this` [la referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this):

> Hace referencia al objeto contexto de JavaScript en el cual se está ejecutando el código actual.

Por otro lado debes saber que el código ejecutado por `setTimeout` [corre en un contexto de ejecución diferente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Explicaci%C3%B3n) al de la función por la que fue llamado, ya que este método pertenece al `mixin` [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope) y es implementada por el objeto [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window). Por lo tanto, cuando haces referencia a `this` dentro de un `setTiemout` estás haciendo referencia a `window`. Observa el siguiente snippet:

```js
var obj = {
  ejecutar: function () {
    console.log(this.toString(), this === obj);
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(this.toString(), this === obj);
    }, 1000);
  } 
};

obj.ejecutar();
```

Esto, se puede resolver de disímiles maneras, la más común es guardar la referencia al contexto deseado en una variable:

```js
var obj = {
  ejecutar: function () {
    var contexto = this;
    console.log(contexto.toString(), contexto === obj);
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(contexto.toString(), contexto === obj);
    }, 1000);
  } 
};

obj.ejecutar();
```

Hacer uso del método [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind):

```js
var obj = {
  ejecutar: function () {
    console.log(this.toString(), this === obj);
    setTimeout((function () {
      console.log(this.toString(), this === obj);
    }).bind(this), 1000);
  } 
};

obj.ejecutar();
```

O hacer uso de [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) introducidas en `ES2015`, ya que estas no cuentan con un contexto propio:

```js
const obj = {
  ejecutar () {
    console.log(this.toString(), this === obj);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.toString(), this === obj);
    }, 1000);
  } 
};

obj.ejecutar();
```

Puedes usar la solución que más te convenga para resolver tu problema, tu código quedaría más o menos así implementando la primera solución:

```
var $input = $('.searchInTable');

$input.keyup(function (e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        table.DataTable().search($input.val()).draw();
    }, delay);
});
```

Comment: Gracias, ahora entiendo el problema en de hacer referencia al objeto equivocado, pero creo que el problema va mas por el como estoy haciendo la consulta a mi datatable ya que intento realizar el filtrado en duro desde la consola "$('#ExampleList').DataTable().search("cualquier texto").draw();"  y esto segun la documentación de datatable me debería traer el texto buscado, pero me indica que faltan parametros... mi tabla tiene 2 columnas "0,1"  y en mi datatable las estoy indicando "aTargets" : [0], "aTargets" : [1]....  y datatable me dice: Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1

Comment: @SamuelCabalLozano, el problema no está en la consulta. Ve a [este enlace](https://codepen.io/MkPrajapati/pen/eweNXY), sitúa en la consola `$('#example').DataTable().search("cualquier texto").draw();` y observa que no lanza ningún _warning_. Tu problema debe estar en otro sitio.

Comment: Podrías intentar reproducir en un snippet tu tabla con el código que usas para poder ver el problema en vivo y detectar dónde está el problema.

Comment: trate de crear el snipet en una respuesta mas arriba, el mismo error que me aparece es el que tengo...  TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Listo ya esta solucionado, estaba creando una tabla con 2 columnas pero en el cuerpo de la tabla solo agregaba una, lo que me daba apertura a 2 cosas, o bien eliminar la columna y su definicion en el datatable o añadir un td vacio para referenciar a la columna no usada.

decidí eliminar la columna no ocupada y quitar la referencia del datatable, me falta hacer pruebas para ver si realmente conviene volver a agregarla por cuestiones de responsividad.

en relación a la busqueda por tiempo, era guardar en una variable lo que esta capturando el keyup y mandarlo al timeout en lugar de buscar desde ahí con el this, justo como dijo @ElChiniNet.
Muchas gracias! seguire haciendo pruebas

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado el resultado. Sería bueno que amplíes la explicación haciéndola más detallada con los fragmentos de código que cambiaste y que resolvieron tu error. Esto ayudará a futuros usuarios con el mismo error, verificar si pueden solucionarlo con tu solución.